Always-On Secondary Replica Stuck in "Disconnected" State
I have 2 nodes in my Always-On and suddenly my secondary replica down and disconnected from AG. I keep getting this error : "An unexpected internal failure occurred when trying to marshal a message. State 26"

There's really not enough to help troubleshoot what seems to be an instance in a bad state. State 26 is attempt SSPI handshaking, so who knows with just this single line. You'll either need to add much more information, such as sql logs, system event logs, app logs, etc., or restart the server and hope that fixes it.
